# как добавить несколько цен ? чтобы по этим всем ценам можно было делать поиск, Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

таблица products БД:
id,
name,
price

есть админка там 
к примеру 
name,
price
и чтобы была возможность добавить еще цену add price

делать сразу в базе в этой таблице фиксированную к примеру 10 штук price1, price2, price3 ...

или правильнее делать отдельную таблицу price
которая имееет
id,
products_id,
price

Comment: Второй вариант, отношение `hasMany`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отдельную.
Ещё в таблицу с ценами можно к примеру добавить дату цены, а потом можно отслеживать изменение цены.
Например

```
table `price`
id
id_product
id_typeprice // тип цены что бы можно было выбрать по id продукту и типу цены 
dataprice
price_summ
```

Таким образом если у одного продукта и одного типа будет две цены с разными датами, можно будет выбрать последнюю, актуальную цену.